# Reassociate .SQL files with VS T-SQL Editor

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, editor

I seem to have lost the association from .sql files to the default VS T-SQL editor.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  When i open a .sql file it opens using a text editor with no syntax highlighting.  How do I reassociate all .sql files with the default T-SQL editor while inside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Edit Registry, copy GUID from key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\9.0\Languages\Language Services\T-SQL\Default
```

Create new key .sql in

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\9.0\Languages\File Extensions`

and default value set to GUID from first step.

Restart VS

Answer (score 0):

in file explorer, right click on the .sql file, chose "open with" then "choose program...", select VS and check "always use..."

Comment: i chose "open with" and don't have the choice of VS.  I have choices of XML, Source Code, HTML, Binary, Resource editors.  I've tried them all (currently using Source Code editor).  I added VS (devenv.exe) as a program and used that but it opened a new instance of VS with the Source Code editor (no syntax highlighting)

Comment: @Scott, the open with list will list window's bets guesses.  Isn't there a "choose program..." option at the bottom?  this will open a dialogue box where you can pick any program you want.

Comment: @KM, thanks for working with me on this, yes i did get a choose program.  That is the option I chose to select VS as in your suggestion.  But which exe do I choose then for the built-in T-SQL editor with visual studio.  I tried selecting VS as you suggested but the exe i chose is devenv.exe and that opened another instance of VS but still used the source code editor with no highlighting.

Comment: @Scott, I don't have VS, so I can't tell you

Answer (score 0):

If you are not in a "SQL Server Project" you don't have the T-SQL Editor (Default Project Editor), just the default one. You can always use the default text editor which is not much different.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Pavel, works like a charm.
In my case I copied the guid from

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\Language
>   Services\T-SQL90\Default

and created a new .sql key in

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Languages\File Extensions

Answer (score 0):

You need to install or re-install some SQL Files from the ISO and it only took me 2 minutes. Namely:

Explore the ISO and go into the WCU folder then into the DAC folder and install the following files:

DACFramework_enu
DACProjectSystemSetup_enu
TSqlLanguageService_enu

That worked for me. I'm using VS 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2